# LSDV/Fixed Effect Model Missing Dummy Variables

Tags: r, least-squares, dummy-variable

- I am completely new at R, and my supervisor has been off sick basically the entire year so I am unable to get help off them, so any help on here would be appreciated! :) I hope I made the below detailed enough.

I am doing an LSDV/fixed-effect model, whereby I am using both region and year as the dummy variables

Using the code:

```
#Dummy Variable
dummyvar = lm(ROE~ESG+Leverage+Age+Size+factor(Region)+factor(Year), data=worlddatapanel)
summary(dummyvar)
```

I get the output: *Unsure how to paste a table onto here, so I took a screenshot*

[image]

**Questions:**

1. I am looking at the year 2012-2020, and 3 regions (Been converted into numbers, i.e., regions 1,2 and 3. However, the output seems to be missing **2012** as the dummy variable, as well as **region 1.** Is there any reason for this?
2. When analysing the data, am I alright to interpret that region 2 and 3, has no effect on ROE. Likewise for the years, apart from 2018-20?
3. Do I perhaps assume the intercept is my results for region 1 that is missing. If not, how do I interpret the results for that line?

List of acronyms/explanation:

- ROE = Return on Equity
- ESG = Corporate social responsibility proxy
- Factor (Region) 2 and 3 are my dummy variables for my regions. *Missing region 1*
- Factor (Year) 2013-2020 are my dummy variables for my sample period. *Missing 2012*

**Thanks in advance, and have a wonderful Easter!**

***EDIT** Anova results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. for the missing of region 1 and year 2012, there are use in the model as the reference to compare effect of others regions and years.
2. to fix your idea on the effect you can perfom this test `anova(dummyvar)`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. That makes much more sense now! I've just updated the post above with the anova table results, I hope you don't mind explaining. But how does one compare and contrast the results when interpreting the analysis, now that the region and all the years are grouped together? The main point of my study was to compare the 3 different regions' results. (Correct me if I'm wrong), but would I just say that there is no correlation for all 3 regions, and there is depending on the year? Thanks!

Comment: I think thet there is no effect of region. The year has some effect and to get more details you have to perform a tukey test **to compare all the means two by two**. Visit this link https://delladata.fr/anova-a-un-facteur-partie-2-la-pratique/. It will be helpfull

Comment: Thank you very much, I just have one more question which I hope you don't mind answering. For the p-values, am I meant to use Pr(>|t|) or Pr(>F) from ANOVA i.e., is there a more suitable one to use? From my understanding, the first one is the p-values from that t-test. And Pr(>F) is the p-value associated with the f value. Thanks!

Comment: As you are checking the global effect of region and year, you should consider the F test but you have to verify the conditions on residuals. I think that you will find all the process in the post that i suggest: Hope you have the english version of the post!